# Dereference array name

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, mpi

In my understanding an array name is not a variable,
so how is it possible for us do dereference it like this:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
void *p = &a;
```

what's the meaning of it?
and why we do all MPI functions require this dereferencing?

```
 int buff[2];
 ...  
 MPI_Bcast(&buff, 2, MPI_INT, PROC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

From Kernighan & Ritchie:

> There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must
>   be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so pa=a and pa++ are legal.
>   But an array name is not a variable; constructions like a=pa and a++
>   are illegal.

Comment: What do you mean by 'an array name is not a variable'? In the call to `MPI_Bcast`, what is the type of `buff`?

Comment: Array name is a pointer to its first element. So, `a==&a[0]`

Comment: Yeah Cool Guy I know that, but it's not a variable.

Comment: It is a variable of type pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All MPI functions take the address of the beginning of the message buffer provided as a `void *`. They do not need a typed pointer since all the information about the layout of the memory in the buffer is provided by the MPI datatype, in that case `MPI_INT`.

```
int buff[2];
...  
MPI_Bcast(&buff, 2, MPI_INT, PROC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This code is technically wrong. `&buff` is an expression of type `int (*)[2]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of two integer elements. Although it evaluates to the same address as `buff` does, it has different semantics with respect to pointer arithmetic.

The proper expression should be:

```
MPI_Bcast(buff, 2, MPI_INT, PROC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

or

```
MPI_Bcast(&buff[0], 2, MPI_INT, PROC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Passing `&buff` is also dangerous because one could later decide to allocate `buff` dynamically instead of statically, e.g. `int *buff = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` Now `&buff` will not point to the beginning of the allocated memory but rather to the address where the pointer resides, which is totally wrong and MPI does not perform pointer chasing. This won't happen if `buff` or `&buff[0]` is used.

Also, note `&` is the *address-of* operator, i.e. it returns a reference. To dereference one uses the `*` operator.

Answer (score -1):

An "array name" doesn't exist. There can be a named variable of a pointer type which points to the first element of the array.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
void *p = &a;
```

`a` is a pointer of type int pointing to the first element, "1".
`p` is a void pointer, and after the assignment it actually points to the location where the address of the arrays first element is stored.

I don't know how your library works. Usually, this pattern is used if the function you're calling should be able to modify the pointer. This for example is "useful" when the library allocates a new array and updates the pointers reference. I write useful in quotes because I don't consider it good practice.

Comment: No, `a` is certainly not "a pointer of type int", it's an array. It's type is `int[5]`. Consider how `printf("the size is %zu\n", sizeof a);` works.

Comment: Well syntactically speaking, I agree. Semantically, isn't it really the same?

Comment: The C standard is pretty clear about what means what: "Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue."

Answer (score -1):

An array is a variable, but it can't be assigned to (you can't "move the array").

The name evaluates to the address of the array's first element in many contexts, but it's not *equivalent* to the address of the first element.

You can use `sizeof` on an array name and get the actual size (in bytes) of the array, which would not be possible if the name was equivalent to a pointer. Like this:

```
int a[4];

printf("the array a has size %zu\n", sizeof a);
```

On a machine with 8-bit `char` and 32-bit `int`, the above will print `16`. This proves that the name `a` refers to something that is *not* just a pointer.